# How can I set @addTagHandler globally in asp.net mvc core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

if i like to use my own TagHelper, i must add

```
@addTagHelper *, MyAssemly
```

in each cshtml-file.

Is it possible to set this global or only one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `_ViewImports.cshtml` to your Views folder, and define your tag helpers there to have them globally on every View.

More info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro